# How do I disable logging for CVSROOT in loginfo?

Tags: logging, cvs, loginfo

I'd like to disable logging for the module `CVSROOT`. I tried:

```
^CVSROOT /bin/cat > /dev/null
```

but that fails with this error:

```
/bin/cat: >: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: /var/cvs/globus/base2/CVSROOT: Is a directory
```

It seems CVS appends some default parameters when I don't specify anything. But I can't use `/bin/cat ${sVv}` because then cat will try to open these "files". I can't use `/bin/true` because then I get broken pipe errors. Also, the redirection seems to fail.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error can come from two sources: The file `loginfo` and the file `commitinfo`.

To disable the logging for `CVSROOT`, you must first add a new script `ignore.sh` to `CVSROOT` (if you're working remotely, just checkout the module `CVSROOT`). The script is pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > /dev/null
exit 0
```

Make sure the script is executable.

Add the name of the script to end the file `checkoutlist` in a line of its own.

Add this rule near the top of `loginfo`:

```
^CVSROOT $CVSROOT/CVSROOT/ignore.sh %{sVv}
```

And this rule near the top of `commitinfo`:

```
^CVSROOT $CVSROOT/CVSROOT/ignore.sh "%r/%p" "%s"
```